# CentOS 7, restoring Mysql database from .sql file

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, centos7

I am on CentOS 7 on a VMWare machine.

I am applying the following command to restore Mysql database from .sql file:

```
[root@mywebhosting /]# mysql -u user –p password portaldb < mysql_dump.sql
```

I hope the command is correct but getting the following message/help:

```
Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
abort-source-on-error             FALSE
auto-rehash                       TRUE
auto-vertical-output              FALSE
binary-as-hex                     FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
column-type-info                  FALSE
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
debug-check                       FALSE
debug-info                        TRUE
database                          (No default value)
default-character-set             auto
delimiter                         ;
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
init-command                      (No default value)
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              localhost
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              0
progress-reports                  FALSE
prompt                            \N [\d]>
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         FALSE
socket                            (No default value)
ssl                               FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
table                             FALSE
user                              portal
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect-timeout                   0
max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
select-limit                      1000
max-join-size                     1000000
secure-auth                       FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
binary-mode                       FALSE
```

I searched a lot and got the same command everywhere.

Any help on what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove space between option short tag and password

```
mysql -u user –ppassword portaldb < mysql_dump.sql
```

Comment: Or export password before processing with 'export MYSQL_PWD=password' and use 'mysql -u user –p portaldb < mysql_dump.sql'

Comment: Removing space between option short tag and password worked. Thanks a lot Didier. But yesterday it was not working, quite weird.

Comment: How dumb I am, I was checking the commands which I ran yesterday, and noticed all of them were having space between "-p" and "password". This thread can be closed now. Thanks for your help.